PHP / Telegram Bot: How to open a URL as Web App not an external Link?
I am creating a Telegram bot for my store with PHP.
Currently I have created the bot, used webhook URL to introduce my bot's PHP file to Telegram. My code almost works and can respond commands I defined, but I have a button/command "Open the store". When we click this button, a message will send to user with this content "Click the button below to open the store:" and a button bellow the message with name "Open store".
In my code I set this button's link $storeURL = 'https://example.com/?username='.$username.'&uid='.$userID; and it works good and could get username and used ID.
The problem is this button will show a pupop with message "Do you want the link? https://example.com/?username=xxxxxxx&uid=1234678", And it will open this link in external browser.
But I need to open this button like a Web App (Mini-App) inside of Telegram not as an external link.
In BotFather I can set a custom URL and Custom Text for menu, this URL open like a webview/internal mini-app. And exactly I need to open the "Open store" button like a mini-app.
How is this possible? I just saw some PHP bots can do it. My website is coded with PHP so for this reason I want to use PHP for my bot. This is my PHP code for bot file in my website:
<?php

$botToken = '6877041912:AAE-LsUBqjuurlBSFA6l6jU_RcbdFO_t000';
$telegramApi = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$botToken;

$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'epfnwgng_farmms';
$password = 'BappJ5CstjY6';
$dbname = 'epfnwgng_farmdbn';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed: '.$conn->connect_error);
}

$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

if (isset($update['message'])) {
    
$chatID = $update['message']['chat']['id'];
$messageText = $update['message']['text'];
$userID = $update['message']['from']['id'];
$username = $update['message']['from']['username'];

switch ($messageText) {
    case '/start':
        sendMessage($chatID, 'Welcome to the Telegram mini app bot! Choose an option below:');
        sendKeyboard($chatID);
        break;
    case 'Open store':
    $storeURL = 'https://example.com/?username='.$username.'&uid='.$userID;
    sendStore($chatID, $storeURL);
    break;
    case 'Referred members':
        $referredMembersCount = getReferredMembersCount($chatID);
        sendMessage($chatID, 'Number of referred members: '.$referredMembersCount);
        break;
    case 'Refer and point':
        $referLink = 'https://t.me/xxxxxxxx_bot?startuid='.$chatID;
        $message = 'Your referral link is '.$referLink.'. Share it and earn points for each user.';
        $referredPlayersCount = getReferredPlayersCount($chatID);
        $message .= "\n\nNumber of players with your UID in the game: ".$referredPlayersCount;
        sendMessage($chatID, $message);
        break;
    default:
        sendMessage($chatID, 'Invalid command. Please choose an option from the keyboard.');
        sendKeyboard($chatID);
}
}

function insertPlayerData($username, $userID) {
    global $conn;
    
    $check_sql = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE username = '$username'";
    $check_result = $conn->query($check_sql);
    
    if ($check_result->num_rows == 0) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO players (username, UID) VALUES ('$username', '$userID')";
        $conn->query($sql);
    }
}

function getReferredMembersCount($chatID) {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS referred_count FROM players WHERE referreduid = $chatID";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    return $row['referred_count'];
}

function getReferredPlayersCount($chatID) {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS referred_players_count FROM players WHERE referreduid = $chatID";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    return $row['referred_players_count'];
}

function sendMessage($chatID, $message) {
    global $telegramApi;
    
    $data = [
        'chat_id' => $chatID,
        'text' => $message
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($telegramApi.'/sendMessage');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

function sendStore($chatID, $storeURL) {
    global $telegramApi;
    $data = [
        'chat_id' => $chatID,
        'text' => 'Click the button below to open the store:',
        'reply_markup' => json_encode([
            'inline_keyboard' => [
                [
                    [
                        'text' => 'Open store',
                        'url' => $storeURL
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ])
    ];
    $ch = curl_init($telegramApi . '/sendMessage');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}


function sendKeyboard($chatID) {
    global $telegramApi;
    $keyboard = [
        ['Open the Store'],
        ['Help', 'Support'],
        ['Referred members', 'Refer and point']
    ];
    $replyMarkup = [
        'keyboard' => $keyboard,
        'resize_keyboard' => true,
        'one_time_keyboard' => false
    ];
    $data = [
        'chat_id' => $chatID,
        'text' => 'Choose an option:',
        'reply_markup' => json_encode($replyMarkup)
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($telegramApi.'/sendMessage');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

?>


Now change your token.

PHP knows nothing about what happens on the client side, you can't control this from PHP. It will be a setting in the front-end app.

P.S. Not sure where you've been learning from, but this is totally the wrong way to build a SQL query using PHP when you're incorporating user input into it. 1) It's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and 2) it can be crashed with simple syntax issues due to the input values  - e.g. anyone with a ' in their name (such as O'Reilly)  would crash your query because SQL would think the ' was terminating the input string after the O.

Instead you must use prepared statements and parameters to correctly build the query and insert the values safely. See How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement, How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP? and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli for some excellent resources and simple examples of how to do this stuff properly. Even as a beginner on a practice project you should get into good habits.

@u_mulder Yes it's already changed some numbers. it's not main token.

@ADyson Thanks. it's just a basic coding and it's not for final deploy, so the sql inject will be update, it's only for developing right now. and for the name, i don't think telegram allow users to use special characters in their username. it will get username, not user display name. but yes we will check security part at end

@ADyson I just see a video on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwiDgTx0QFI that someone created a bot with PHP and could manage to open the button like WebApp (mini-app). This is what I want to know.

@TLPMasih Do you have this in mind? https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps

@Eduard Almost yes. This feature is Mini App but it works for "Menu", that we can set a custom menu title and menu URL, and it will open a URL. The look how it open is what I want but there are two problems: 1. I can't use dynamic parameters for the URL. 2. It will clear user cache after closing and reopening the URL so everything user add in cart will remove. I need this cache in highest priority.

the sql inject will be update, it's only for developing right now....ok, but why waste your time coding it twice, when you already know there's a safer and more reliable way to do it? It isn't any more difficult or complex to use parameterised queries, and as well as the security issues it also removes the risk of accidental syntax errors as I mentioned - so by doing it this way during development you actually increase the complexity and risk instead of reducing it. I can't imagine why you'd choose this route if you know the correct way. But it's up to you, of course

i don't think telegram allow users to use special characters in their username....ok but SQL injection isn't about "special" characters and anyway there's nothing "special" about a ' particularly (Telegram may have other reasons if they don't allow it in a username). But it's irrelevant anyway - you can't guarantee (unless you have good authentication) that some other client or system won't try to connect to your PHP script and send malicious data, and also it's about the principle of building your queries correctly in all cases, not just this one. You're somewhat missing the point.
